# koa2 in multer TypeError: fn.apply is not a function

Tags: node.js, multer, koa2

I am studying koa2 using [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to post images to a server.

mine usage like the document 
it show

```
TypeError: fn.apply is not a function
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/node_modules/.2.4.2@koa-route/index.js:34:19)
      at next (native)
      at onFulfilled (/Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/node_modules/.4.6.0@co/index.js:65:19)
      at /Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/node_modules/.4.6.0@co/index.js:54:5
      at Object.co (/Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/node_modules/.4.6.0@co/index.js:50:10)
      at converted (/Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/node_modules/.1.2.0@koa-convert/index.js:17:15)
      at dispatch (/Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/node_modules/.3.2.1@koa-compose/index.js:44:32)
      at next (/Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/node_modules/.3.2.1@koa-compose/index.js:45:18)
      at dispatch (/Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/node_modules/.7.0.0@koa-router/lib/router.js:315:32)
      at dispatch (/Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/node_modules/.3.2.1@koa-compose/index.js:44:32)
      at next (/Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/node_modules/.3.2.1@koa-compose/index.js:45:18)
      at /Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/templating.js:32:15
      at next (native)
      at step (/Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/templating.js:1:191)
      at /Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/templating.js:1:437
      at /Users/MacBook/Documents/nodeSutdy/nodeweb6/templating.js:1:99

(node:2696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
```

My code

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const controller = require('./controller');
const templating = require('./templating');
const route = require('koa-route');
const multer = require('koa-multer');
const session = require('koa-session');
const convert = require('koa-convert');
const mount_uploadify = require('koa-uploadify');
const upload = multer({dis:"./uploads"});
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const app = new Koa();
app.keys=['a','b'];
app.use(session(app));
// parse request body:
app.use(bodyParser());
// log request URL:
app.use(async (ctx,next) => {
    console.log(`Process ${ctx.request.method} ${ctx.request.url}...`);
    var
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        execTime;
    await next();
    execTime = new Date().getTime() - start;
    ctx.response.set('X-Response-Time', `${execTime}ms`);
});

// static file support:
if (! isProduction) {
    let staticFiles = require('./static-files');
    app.use(staticFiles('/static/', __dirname + '/static'));
}



// add nunjucks as view:
app.use(templating('views', {
    noCache: !isProduction,
    watch: !isProduction
}));

// add controller:
app.use(controller());
app.use(convert(route.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'))));
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do, how is it supposed to work?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do the site tour (click "help" on the top bar), read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [how to create a clear problem description](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please avoid quoting error strings, use the code sample button (or indent the whole block 4 spaces). To avoid syntax highlighting of the error, add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` just before.

Comment: thx now  i got it